# Access denied when using net stop/start via CLI on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I have a Windows service that needs to be stopped and restarted when switching to a different development server (I'm a web developer.) If I go into the Services GUI, I can stop and restart the service with no problem. My colleague has a batch file that works for him, so I tried to use it, and it's giving me Access Denied errors. I've tried running the file as administrator, and even just running the commands directly in the cmd window. Still get the error.

The file is simply:

```
net stop "Service Integration Gateway"
net start "Service Integration Gateway"
pause
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode) answer on StackOverflow, and tried using the `runas` command like this:

```
runas /user:Administrator net stop "Service Integration Gateway"
```

but all it did was give me the readme on `runas`, so I'm guessing I can't use it with the `net stop` command, or I'm using it wrong.

What do I need to do to be able to run these commands via CLI/batch?

**EDITED TO ADD SCREENSHOT AS REQUESTED:**

[image: Running as Admin]

[image]

Comment: In your picture, your CMD window is NOT running "as administrator"; can you provide a screenshot of it failing in a command prompt that's been "run as administrator"?  As to your RunAs toubles, the "program" needs to be a single string that contains both the program and options, so you'll want to encapsulate it in quotes (and escape the inner quotes) like this: `runas /user:Administrator "net stop \"Service Integration Gateway\""` See `runas /?` for more information...

Comment: Try quoting the whole command: `runas /user:Administrator "net stop \"Service Integration Gateway\""`

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I've added a screenshot of the cmd window running as admin. As you can see, the error message is the same.

Comment: It still doesn't appear that you're running the command-prompt "As administrator", as I would expect the window title to be prefixed with "As Administrator: " to signify it.   Instead of however you are launching CMD try this instead:  Click Start, type CMD, and when it appears on the start menu, right-click it and choose "Run as administrator".

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I'll provide a video if necessary - I'm running the prompt as administrator. It gave me the popup confirm when I clicked the shortcut to it. It does the same thing if I do it via the start menu as you detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your command prompt screenshot doesn't say "Administrator" at the front so I think possibly you are not doing "run as administrator" correctly. Make sure to right click the bat file and do "run as administrator" which has a yellow/blue shield icon. Do NOT use "run as different user" or assume when logged on as an admin that you have full admin rights. UAC prevents certain actions without further elevation.

[image]

[image]